# How to manually set touchpad click regions?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, hp

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 on an HP Envy x360 laptop, and it has an extremely annoying touchpad, where the middle ~2/3 of the touchpad acts as middle click and only ~1/6 on either side of this acts as left/right click. This is constantly causing problems when I'm trying to left click on something, and it middle clicks instead causing it to randomly paste text, enable autoscrolling, etc.

What I would like do is change it so that the opposite is the case. I want the middle 1/6 of the touchpad to act as middle click, and I want the 5/12 of the pad on either side to act as right or left click. Basically, I only want middle click to occur if I tap exactly on the middle of the touchpad, and I want to have a much wider region allocated to left/right click.

Is there a way to manually set the regions on the touchpad where each type of clicking (left/middle/right) will occur?